# Remove unnecessary dependencies in POM

Tags: java, maven, ant, pom.xml, dependency-management

I am new to Maven and I faced a problem when I tried to convert my current project from using Ant -> using Maven.

That project requires many Jars, and I look up those jars on mvnrepository and add all to POM.xml.

I don't know if some dependency is redundant.

Do you guy know any way to check if which dependency which I really need?

Answer (score 1):

The [Maven dependency analyzer plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/analyze-mojo.html) is just what you're looking for.

Just run

```
mvn install dependency:analyze
```

(on some platforms, for some reason, the full notation is required:)

```
mvn install org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.9:analyze
```

And review the report it produces.